# Frame Rate drops to 30 with Dell P2415Q 4K

Tags: macbook-pro, display

MBP: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016)

macOS: Mojave 10.14

Display: [Dell 2415Q](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-24-ultra-hd-4k-monitor-p2415q/apd/210-agnk/monitors-monitor-accessories)

Connection: [ANKER](https://www.anker.com/products/variant/premium-usb-c-hub-with-hdmi-and-power-delivery/A8342042) Premium USB-C Hub with HDMI

I have done an FPS test and it's only 30 (which should be 60). Is it possible to make it a 60 FPS rate? What can I do?

Update: Anker is innocent. It's NOT Anker's problem.

Comment: When did you get 60?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried many ways and finally the Dell official Twitter support helped me out:

It's because HDMI is only able to run at 30Hz so I just simply changed it to a DP (Display Port) cable. It's perfect now.

BTW, I haven't tried HDMI-DP cable, I am using a USBC-DP cable.

Comment: using a DP cable did indeed fix this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to Anker's community site  (which is unofficial, community backed) the USB-C hub only supports 4k at 30 Hz. You would then never be able to achieve 60 fps with this hardware.

I would contact Anker's customer support and get this confirmed, and see if you have any means of returning the product for a refund with the seller.

Comment: It was on the community site - I cannot remember the link now. You can contact Anker support for clarification.

Comment: I tried another cable and I realize it's not Anker's fault. I believe it's Dell's problem. Here is a spec: `Native Resolution
4K UHD (2160p) 3840 x 2160 (DisplayPort: 60 Hz, HDMI: 30 Hz)` Feel bad for Dell.